# Looking for difficulties or limitations encountered using Records Center as a document management system

Tags: list-view-threshold, records-management, records-center

My company is currently considering various records management options. My leaning is that we should use SharePoint primarily as a front-end, while the bulk of data would be stored externally. However, our consultant is pushing storing the documents in SharePoint.

Can anyone share success or failures implementing and using a Records Center for large volumes of data/documents?  I'm concerned with whether OOTB limitations, such as list view thresholds, interfere with practical use of the Records Center. I'd also like to know if anyone has had great success with it, and whether the solution includes third-party products.

Comment: You would have to define what you consider as an record and scales you are talking about. For example why are you concerned with list views. Sharepoint solution can scale well but like any other platform needs careful planning when it comes to scaling it. If your user scenarios predict heavy queries, they could be offloaded to search especially if you have many uniquely secured items.

Comment: @MarekSarad have you ever implemented a SharePoint Records Center?

Comment: yes several times(some QMS and legal HR ). Underneath RC is just specialized library in SP terms, some elements are turned off (like doc parser) for better scalability. One thing to watch out on SP are collections with a lot of item level security. Those can be a headache to work with using standard approach, in those cases I move to search driven menus, navigation etc. Sharepoint search index is very effective way of working with large collections even if they have fine grained permissions.

Comment: How many documents were you working with? Were you able to keep all libraries under the 5000 item threshold, or did you have larger libraries and rely on folder and search?

Comment: Large libraries and pure search (sometimes we remove the standard views, to ensure users don't stray from the right path) or sometimes mix of folders and search, but 50-100k per library(RC).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for records management or document management? Records center is for long term storage of records, which are finalized copies of documents, like approved contracts. To actually write the contract, that would be done on a non-records center site, like a "team site". Do people use SharePoint to handle large volumes of docs? Yes. Though of course, the design of the farm and how many docs are being processed will be key to that.

Comment: I am asking specifically about a Records Center, not Document Center or any other site template. (It just happens that our records will be documents.) I'm also not asking whether people do it, as I know there are companies who do. I'm looking for people who have actually implemented it on a large scale (and please share what large scale means for you) and whether they ran into issues or felt it was successful. I think most of us who work with SharePoint long enough end up implementing something OOTB and find it works better in theory than in real life.